# aurelia validation for dynamic json objects

Tags: aurelia

I am using Aurelia framework for my new application, i am having problem configuring and using aurelia validation plugin, i have a json object that is returned by the server, based on certain selection from the checkbox list, i have to pass the subset of the json object to a child view via compose element. somehow i am not able to understand how to configure it properly based on the examples i found, i am not able to validate input elements in the child view. here is the json  sample below

```
  var selectedTopicValues={ "Contact":"",
  "billing": {
    "Quantity": {
      "TicketFieldTypeID": 2,
      "TicketTopicID": 7,
      "Value": [
        "Quantity"
      ],
      "Required": true,
      "DisplayName": "Quantity"
    },
    "SameasContact": {
      "TicketFieldTypeID": 9,
      "TicketTopicID": 7,
      "Value": [],
      "Required": true,
      "DisplayName": "Same as contact",
      "IsActive": false
    }
  },
  "coupencoderequest": {
    "RequestType": {
      "TicketFieldTypeID": 2,
      "TicketTopicID": 7,
      "Value": [
        ""
      ],
      "Required": true,
      "DisplayName": "Request Type"
    }
  }
};
```

if the user selects billing, then i need pass the billing related object to the child view by using compose and binding it to model.bind property. The validation needs to be done on the "Value" properties. ex: "billing.Quantity.Value".

The validation should trigger when the user clicks save button present in the main-view.html

the input element configured below works when click save

```
 <md-input md-label="First Name" md-validate="true" value.bind="selectedTopicValues.Contact & validate:rules"></md-input>
```

the one below does not work, and this element is present in the child view

```
<md-input md-label="Quantity"   md-value.bind="billing.Quantity.Value & validate:rules"  md-text-area="true"> </md-input>
```

parentview.ts

```
    import {inject, customElement,NewInstance} from 'aurelia-framework';
    import {Validator,ValidationController,ValidationRules} from 'aurelia-validation';

    import { MaterializeFormValidationRenderer } from 'aurelia-materialize-bridge';

    @inject(Validator,ticketModel,ValidationController)
    export class parentview {
selectedTopicValues={}//json 
    constructor(validator,controller:ValidationController) {


    this.controller=controller;
    this.controller.addRenderer(new MaterializeFormValidationRenderer());
    this.addRules();
    }

    AddRules()
      {
        this.rules.push(ValidationRules.ensure('Contact').required().rules[0]);
        let rules1=[];
        jQuery.each(this.selectedTopicValues, function (key, data) {

        jQuery.each(data, function (index, data2) {

          rules1.push(ValidationRules
        .ensure(key+"."+data2.DisplayName+".Value")
          .required().rules[0]);
        })
    });
    this.rules.push(rules1);

    this.controller.addObject(this.selectedTopicValues,this.rules);

      }

     save() {
       console.log(this.selectedTopicValues);
      var v=  this.controller.validate({object:this.selectedTopicValues,rules:this.rules}).then(v => {
          if (v.length === 0) {
            console.log( 'All is good!');
          } else {

            console.log( 'You have errors!'+ v.length);
          }
        });;
      console.log(v);
      }
}
```

I need some help or direction regarding validations on dynamic json objects.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `md-value.bind="billing.quantity.Value` is this a typo in your source code or in your question? Because according to your json it should be `md-value.bind="billing.Quantity.Value`

Comment: its a typo in the question, sorry about that

Comment: Sorry, I don't have the time to repro this myself with what you've provided. Could you make a git or a gist (you could use this one https://gist.run/?id=3082404c8b8ec05a66e54b856db2162d) that shows the problem? Then I'll be glad to help you make it work.

Comment: i have updated it here https://gist.run/?id=d7f9d7dfe98b02c860f926409b87ba00 however i was not able to make it run properly :( .I am using materialize bridge component too but not sure if that gets loaded in gist properly. sorry i m quiet new to these javascript frameworks

Comment: `md-value.bind="billing.Quantity.Value` does that binding work without validation?

Comment: yes... it worked.But using md custom components is not a need in my case, i can use regular input elements

Comment: See my answer. Just a small piece of advice: next time try creating a small github project or something (especially when there is no concrete error). It took me more than half an hour to get it all to work and figure out your code, for only 2 minutes of debugging and seeing what the problem/solution is. If you spend that half an hour yourself, you'll probably gain immensely from it in the form of more/faster answers.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate for your help. I will consider uploading small github project next time. I am still facing issues when trying to bind these elements in child pages due to this and also considering project  deadlines i had to switch to jquery validation for now.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is the dynamic property accessor: `.ensure(key+"."+data2.DisplayName+".Value").`

Let's assume the first rule that you generate, `billing.Quantity.Value`.

What you are expecting it to do:
`selectedTopicValues["billing"]["Quantity"]["Value"]`

What it really does: `selectedTopicValues["billing.Quantity.Value"]` (a single property with that name does not exist, obviously)

I was a little surprised by this at first since `aurelia-binding` does parse periods in accessors into nested expressions. So this behavior is actually more consistent with a normal `PropertyObserver`

Presumably, this is where it goes wrong (line 108): https://github.com/aurelia/validation/blob/master/src/implementation/standard-validator.ts

It should be possible, though, so I think I'm going to submit a feature request for this.

**A solution**

I tried this and it seems to work:

```
public addRules() {
    this.rules.push(...ValidationRules.ensure("Contact").required().on(this.selectedTopicValues).rules);

    jQuery.each(this.selectedTopicValues, (index1, value1) => {

        jQuery.each(value1, (index2, value2) => {

            if (value2.Required) {
                this.rules.push(...ValidationRules
                    .ensure("Value") // .ensure(x => x.Value) is also possible
                    .displayName(value2.DisplayName)
                    .required()
                    .on(value2)
                    .rules);
            }
        })
    });

    this.controller.addObject(this.selectedTopicValues, this.rules);
}
```

And the view:

```
<md-input md-label="First Name" md-validate="true" md-value.two-way="selectedTopicValues.Contact & validate:rules"></md-input>
<md-input md-label="Quantity" md-validate="true" md-value.two-way="selectedTopicValues.billing.Quantity.Value & validate:rules"  md-text-area="true"> </md-input>
```

What I changed:

- Directly pass the "leaf object" (which actually contains the Value property) to the validator via `.on()`
- Use the `...` [spread operator](https://rainsoft.io/how-three-dots-changed-javascript/) to add all your rules to a flat list
- Use more of the information from your JSON (assuming you were trying to go into that direction anyway)
- Changed the binding declarations in your view to explicit `two-way` (otherwise they will only be `two-way` when inside a `form` element by convention)

Some additional cleanup and/or binding refreshing may need to be done when the underlying object changes. I can't judge that without seeing the actual code.